# does it make sense to test whether undeclared variable was defined earlier in code?

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm studying JavaScript and have no programming background at all. In this example I think I understand that foo is an undeclared (global) variable that doesn't exist when bar is calculated, so bar = (undefined + 1) or NaN.

```
var bar = foo + 1,
    foo = 1;
```

Let's say this is toward the end of a long bunch of code. What if foo had been defined previously and foo = 1 is intended to re-set the value of foo? Does it make sense to test for it? I think I'm opening up a scope can of worms.... ("Scope? You can't haaaandle the scope!")

I thank you all in advance for your patience with my learning curve! Any answers you could phrase in analogy or metaphor would help my get this under my belt....

Comment: It might just be me, but I don't understand what you're asking :S Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: This is more of a conceptual issue that may be *subjective.* That being said, I am part of the group of programmers that operates around the fact that *it is okay for a program to break.* If `foo` is never intended to be undefined, checking for whether it is NaN is superfluous, as the flow of the program fails when it is NaN.

Comment: I also don't understand. "*What if foo had been defined previously and foo = 1 is intended to re-set the value of foo? Does it make sense to test for it?*" -- Do you want to reset the value of `foo`? If so, do it. If you don't, don't do it. I'm afraid I'm can't quite see the heart of your question. It seems to have something to do with `bar`'s relationship to `foo`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can test and declare of not already declared using the OR operator ||

```
foo = foo || 1;
```

So if foo exists, foo will be foo.  If foo does not exist, foo will be 1.

Comment: Careful with that, because if foo == 0 foo will be set to 1 even though foo IS declared and has a value.

Comment: Great catch. I've actually only ever used this for objects, not primitives that may suffer from type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, although it depends on context. You are declaring new variables. So you are right, if `foo` doesn't exist in the scope, `bar` will be NaN. But foo will not overwrite a global foo, if this code runs in a local scope.

The snippet below shows this: `bar` is NaN both of the times, but the local `foo` that gets the value `2`, doesn't alter the value of the global `foo` that keeps the value `1`.

```js
var bar = foo + 1,
    foo = 1;

document.write('global bar = ' + bar + '<br>');
document.write('global foo = ' + foo + '<br>');


(function() {
  var bar = foo + 1,
      foo = 2;

  document.write('local bar = ' + bar + '<br>');
  document.write('local foo = ' + foo + '<br>');
  
}());

document.write('global foo = ' + foo + '<br>');
```

Output:

> global bar = NaN
>   global foo = 1
>   local bar = NaN
>   local foo = 2
>   global foo = 1